# Extract current YEAR from sheet name which contains months

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

=MID(CELL("filename",AM4),FIND("]",CELL("filename",AM4))+1,255)

Hey all,
      Im Using the above to get the sheet name which are months, but to return the current year. For example we are currently September so through to December will be 2019 and January to August will be 2020

The formula above returns the month ok, but cannot convert to year

Does anyone have any ideas

Comment: Could you provide the complete "filename"?

Comment: @Lee "filename" is an argument of the CELL() function

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this formula:*

```
=2000+RIGHT(MID(CELL("filename"),(FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1),255),2)
```

**N.B.**

- Enter this formula in any required cell.
- Replace `2000` with `2001` in the formula to get year as `2020`.
- Sheet Name is `Sept 2019`.
- Excel only considers the Year value, may be like `Sept 2019` or, `Sept 19` or even `09-2019`.

Comment: Is there no way of not having the year in the sheet name

Comment: As I would like to keep just months as sheetname as January etc

Comment: @Steven,, yeah this formula works for that also,, look I've added this `09-2019` & this `Sept 2019` with above solution!!